# How can I display individual products on my page

Tags: javascript

I just started full stack development and I'm currently working with node, js and django. On my home page I have 2 products(express) but when I click on an individual product I get redirected to a blank page and I'm not sure why

Here is my code for individual product

```
window.onload = ()=>{
    let params = window.location.search;
  let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(params);
  let productID = urlParams.get("id");
  // http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/id 
  if(productID != null && typeof(productID)!= 'undefined'){
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/'+productID)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          if('detail' in data){
              // display some generic product not found error
          }
          else{
              let name = data['name'];
              let desc = data['description'];
              let price = data['price'];
              let image= data['image'];
                            // display the product data 
                            
          }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: This code runs when your page loads, it doesn't seem to have any relationship to clicking on anything. It also doesn't even attempt to display anything from the results of the fetch() call. Can we have more context please?

Comment: ok so I have a django page with 2 products which when i run the django server and the node server they get displayed on the node home page. I want to make it so when I click on a product it brings me to a new page which displays details about this product (price, picture, etc)

Comment: Ok. Leaving aside for moment why you're seemingly using two completely separate frameworks at the same time for one application, what part is the code above supposed to be playing in that process?

Comment: the above code is supposed to display the product i clicked on, on its own individual page.

Comment: Well all it does is try to fetch some data from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/`. You next need to write some code to actually display what is fetched. So far all you have is some comments which suggest where to put such code.

Comment: I see.. would you be able to give me a hand with what code to write if you dont mind? I've been trying to do it all morning but havent found anything to work yet unfortunately..

Comment: Well what have you tried exactly? I don't know what the returned data looks like and I don't know how you want the display to look, and I don't know what you've tried already and what went wrong, so it's unclear what the requirements are and it's unclear where you're up to in terms of general knowledge, specific problems etc. Therefore I really have no starting point from which to help you in any more detail. I'm assuming you'll use general JS DOM manipulation functions to create and insert the elements you need in the page, and inject the data contents into them.

Comment: Or maybe you have in mind to use a more sophisticated templating engine, or something else, IDK. We're starting from too low a base for anyone to really be able to give you meaningful advice. You need to decide on your approach and try to implement something, then ask here if you have a specific issue in your code. There are many tutorials etc online which can provide generic ideas on how to get data from an AJAX request and display it on the page. There are many techniques you can use, potentially.